# In the UI I pass a Text but while saving its passing as "null" in approve remarks

Tags: java

My controller.java file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveRiskRuleApproveNew", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public Map<String, String> saveRiskRuleApproveNew(@RequestParam String status,String ruleId,String approveRemarks,String riskInstruction, HttpSession session) {
            Map<String, String> Resultmap = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                logger.info("Saving saveRiskRuleApproveNew:::");
                UserBean userBean = (UserBean)session.getAttribute("user");
                //riskService.saveRiskRuleApprove(riskRuleDTO,userBean);
                riskService.saveRiskRuleApproveNew(status,ruleId,approveRemarks,riskInstruction,userBean);
                if(status.equals("approve"))
                {
                 Resultmap.put(ScrutinyCommonConstants.SUCCESS_MSG, ScrutinyCommonConstants.SUCCESS_APRROVED);
                }
                
                if(status.equals("reject"))                 
                {
                    Resultmap.put(ScrutinyCommonConstants.SUCCESS_MSG, ScrutinyCommonConstants.SUCCESS_REJECTED);
                }
           } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error(ScrutinyCommonConstants.EXCEPTION_OCCURED + ex);
                Resultmap.put(ScrutinyCommonConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE, ScrutinyCommonConstants.ERROR_DATA);
            }
            return Resultmap;
        }
```

Service.java:

```
void saveRiskRuleApproveNew(String status,String ruleId,String approveRemarks,String riskInstruction, UserBean userBean);
```

Serviceimpl.java:

```
@Override
    public void saveRiskRuleApproveNew(String status,String ruleId,String approveRemarks,String riskInstruction, UserBean userBean) {
        riskModuleDao.saveRiskRuleApproveNew(status,ruleId,approveRemarks,riskInstruction,userBean);
    }
```

Dao.java:

```
void saveRiskRuleApproveNew(String status,String ruleId,String approveRemarks,String riskInstruction, UserBean userBean);
```

Daoimpl.java:

```
    @Override
    public void saveRiskRuleApproveNew(String status,String ruleId,String approveRemarks,String riskInstruction, UserBean userBean) {
        try {
            Session session = getSession();
             if(status.equals("approve"))
             {                   
                    Query updatequery = session.createNativeQuery("UPDATE CBEC_GST.SCRTY_RISK_RULE SET APPROVAL_STATUS ='APPROVED',APRV_REMARKS='"+approveRemarks+"',RISK_RULE_INST='"+riskInstruction+"',APPROVED_BY='"+userBean.getSsoId()+"' WHERE UI_RULE_ID = '"+ruleId+"'");
                    updatequery.executeUpdate();
                    session.flush();
             }
             if(status.equals("reject"))
             {                   
                    Query updatequery = session.createNativeQuery("UPDATE CBEC_GST.SCRTY_RISK_RULE SET APPROVAL_STATUS ='REJECTED',APRV_REMARKS='"+approveRemarks+"',RISK_RULE_INST='"+riskInstruction+"',APPROVED_BY='"+userBean.getSsoId()+"' WHERE UI_RULE_ID = '"+ruleId+"'");
                    updatequery.executeUpdate();
                    session.flush();
             }           
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            logger.error(CommonConstants.EXCEPTION_OCCURED, e);
            throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage(), RiskModuleDaoImpl.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(CommonConstants.EXCEPTION_OCCURED, e);
            throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please do the following: 1) format your post to have the code properly highlighted, indented etc. to make it even readable. 2) Elaborate on your question rather than putting just some notion of it into the title and throwing code at us. What are you trying to do and what do you get? Where in your code did you see things go wrong? Did you step through your code with a debugger already?

Comment: Yes, I did a debug. Since am new to java not sure where am making mistakes. I need to save the data. All other datas are getting saved which i pass. Only approve remarks is getting saved in the DB as "null". In the front end I pass a text . Example approve remarks as Approved. But hile saving its reflecting as "Null". Sorry if am still confusing

Comment: You should be able to trace `approveRemarks` through your services and see where it becomes null. If it's in the controller already then there's a mismatch between how your front end is sending it and what the controller expects. Btw, you should _never_ directly concat values into queries, i.e. `"...APRV_REMARKS='"+approveRemarks+"',..."` is a big no-no! (Security reasons) Use parameter placeholders (e.g. `"...APRV_REMARKS=? ..."`) and `query.setParameter(...)` instead.